# Using ActionListener to add new element

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jpanel

Hey everyone I have a button that is supposed to add a new ball to the ArrayList I have set up. Instead of adding a new ball it just speeds up the ball that I already have going.
This CreateCircle creates the ball:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CreateCircle extends JPanel {
/* Ports JFrame width, height from BouncingDrawFrame */
static double c, d;
/* Ports desired size of Circle */
static int r = 20; // Initial Value 20
/* Ports timer delay from BouncingDrawFrame */
static int z = 10; // Initial Value 10
/* Timer to control speed */
static Timer t = new Timer(z, null);
/* X,Y points to start, speed of movement */
static double x, y, velX = 1, velY = 1;
/* Ports color choice from BouncingDrawFrame */
static Color myColor;

public CreateCircle(int a, int b) {
    /* Height of Frame */
    c = a;
    /* Width of Frame */
    d = b;

    t.start();

    t.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            /* "Bounces" the Ball off the sides */
            if (x < 0 || x > (d - (r + 2))) {
                velX = -velX;
            }
            /* "Bounces" the Ball off the top and bottom */
            if (y < 0 || y > (c - (r + 30))) {
                velY = -velY;
            }
            /* Moves ball 2 pixels each timer action */
            x += velX;
            y += velY;
            repaint();
        }

    });
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    Ellipse2D circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, r, r);
    g2.setColor(myColor);
    g2.fill(circle);

}
}
```

While this is the class that handles the buttons and if clicked creates a new ball:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BouncingDrawFrame extends JFrame {
public BouncingDrawFrame() {
    /*
     * Create ArrayList to hold balls, remember ArrayList is not a component
     * but the elements of ArrayList are
     */
    final ArrayList<CreateCircle> ballList = (ArrayList<CreateCircle>) new ArrayList<CreateCircle>();

    /* Create Main Ball Frame */
    final JFrame main = new JFrame();
    main.setTitle("Bouncing Balls!!");
    main.setSize(350, 500);
    main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    main.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    main.setVisible(true);

    /* Create Control Panel */
    JFrame control = new JFrame();
    control.setSize(300, 300);
    control.setTitle("Change Settings!");
    control.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    control.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    control.setVisible(true);

    final JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 2));
    control.add(p1);

    final JButton addBall = new JButton("Add A Ball");
    p1.add(addBall);

    /* Y Point */
    final int a = main.getHeight();
    /* X Point */
    final int b = main.getWidth();

    ballList.add(new CreateCircle(a, b));
    main.add(ballList.get(0));

    addBall.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        private int click;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            click++;
            ballList.add((click), new CreateCircle(a, b));
            System.out.println(click);
            System.out.println(ballList.size());
            main.add(ballList.get(click));
            repaint();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Instead of creating a new ball, clicking the button just speeds up the movement of the first ball. I am trying to add a new ball to the index of the ArrayList that equals the clicked amount. I have the ArrayList size and clicked number output to the system so I know that the ArrayList is increasing in size in conjunction with times clicked. I just don't know why it is not adding a new CreateCircle.

PS: here is the main thread.

```
public class BouncingRun {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new BouncingDrawFrame();
}
}
```

Comment: You have a significant over-use of the static modifier. **Edit** -- as I now see that Jason C states in an answer. 1+ to his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every field in your `CreateCircle` class is `static`, meaning that they are shared between all instances of a `CreateCircle`. Essentially this means that every calculation you do on one of the balls happens on every ball, and that every ball is the same.

You will have to make those not `static` if you want those properties to be associated with specific instances of a `CreateCircle`.

You may wish to take a look at the official tutorial on instance and class members at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html.

Update based on your question re: flicker below: I've created an example (http://pastebin.com/w1D9H6k2) of bouncing JLabels that shows how you can do this and let Swing take care of the repainting and such. It's also here:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BouncingLabels extends JFrame {

    // this is our bouncing label component. it bounces around its parent. this could
    // be pulled out into its own class file; its in here to keep the example self
    // contained.
    static class BouncingLabel extends JLabel {

        private int fieldWidth, fieldHeight; // width/height of parent at creation time.
        private int velX = 1, velY = 1; // current x and y velocity.

        // constructor sets base label properties and starts a timer.
        public BouncingLabel (int fieldWidth, int fieldHeight) {

            this.fieldWidth = fieldWidth;
            this.fieldHeight = fieldHeight;

            setBounds(0, 0, 60, 20);
            setOpaque(true);
            setBackground(Color.RED);
            setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            setText("HELLO");
            setVisible(true);

            // timer will call step() every 10ms.
            new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
                @Override public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
                    step();
                }
            }).start();

        }

        // step updates the component position. note that no explicit painting is done.
        private void step () {

            int x = getX();
            int y = getY();
            int maxx = fieldWidth - getWidth();
            int maxy = fieldHeight - getHeight();

            x += velX;
            y += velY;

            if ((x >= maxx && velX > 0) || (x <= 0 && velX < 0))
                velX = -velX;
            if ((y >= maxy && velY > 0) || (y <= 0 && velY < 0))
                velY = -velY;

            setLocation(x, y);

        }

    }

    // BouncingLabels is our main frame; click on it to add a label.
    public BouncingLabels () {

        // work with the content pane, not the frame itself.
        final Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        c.setLayout(null);
        setResizable(false);
        pack();

        // add an initial bouncing object.
        c.add(new BouncingLabel(c.getWidth(), c.getHeight()));

        // clicking on the frame will add a new object.
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
                    c.add(new BouncingLabel(c.getWidth(), c.getHeight()));
            }            
        });

    }

    // main method creates and shows a BouncingLabels frame.
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run () {
                BouncingLabels b = new BouncingLabels();
                b.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                b.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                b.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

If you wanted to draw, for example, balls instead of labels, you could extend e.g. a `JComponent` and the code is basically the same, except you override `paint()` to tell Swing how to draw your component -- you wouldn't need to worry about the ball position or anything like that in your `paint()` implementation; Swing already maintains the component's position and size. You would just have to draw a circle in the component's coordinate frame.

Comment: Thank You that worked, I removed the static modifier from all of the variables and fields, however now when I create a new ball, it is flickering. Do I need to put repaint() anywhere?

Comment: Your code has many issues; in particular each time you add a `CreateCircle`, since it's a component, its geometry is determined by the main pane's layout manager (BTW you should be adding to `main.getContentPane()`, not to `main`). What you're actually doing is creating a bunch of custom components, all which take up the entire frame and overlap each other. You need to rework your code to rely on more of the existing features of a `JPanel` -- use the underlying `JPanel`s X, Y, width, and height properties, draw an ellipse relative to that, and use a null layout manager. Let Swing do the work.

Comment: I have added an example.

Comment: I have edited your code and allowed me to add balls on a button click however i am trying to remove balls on button 3 click but can only remove the first ball 'code'public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    int click = 0;
    if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
     click++;
     ballList.add(click,
       new CreateCircle(c.getWidth(), c.getHeight()));
     c.add(ballList.get(click));
    }
    if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
     c.remove(ballList.get(click));
     click--;

    } and it only removes the first ball

Comment: Unfortunately, you're on your own from here. We can't keep fixing issues as soon as they come up, and you will have to spend some time troubleshooting, analyzing, and solving your problem. You will learn more that way anyways. If you are running into a new issue that you cannot solve, please create a new question, and show your attempted solutions, expected and actual results.